# binding not works with user instance

Tags: javascript, angular

When typing on the text box, `angulars form value change but

> > userModel value  does not change
>
> , always showing [Vino] in the userModel value.

`

This is the app.component.html,

```
<form #userForm="ngForm">
  {‌{userForm.value | json}}
  <hr />
  {‌{userModel | json}}
<div class="form-group">
<label>Name:</label>
<input type=text class="form-control" name="userName" [(ngModel)]=userModel.name>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type=”submit”>Submit form</button>
</form>
</div>
```

This is app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
userModel=['Vino'];
}
```

This is the user.ts file,

```
export class User {
    constructor(
    public name: string,
    ){}
}
```

Comment: userModel is a array, when we bind userModel.name it will be updated as `["Vino", name: "Submit123"]` but still the length of the array will be 1 so to achieve your expectation change the model binding into `[(ngModel)]="userModel[1]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are binding wrongly the input to userModel which is an array and doesn't have the field name

Answer (score 1):

In your app.component change user model to object like

```
export class AppComponent {
userModel={name:'Vino'};
}
```

and then in HTML your input should be like

```
<input type=text class="form-control" name="userName" [(ngModel)]="userModel.name">
```

Comment: Only changes form value, not the userModel value.

Answer (score 0):

you do not have name property in userModel actually it is an array.
your userModel should be like this.

```
userModel={
           name:'vivo'
          }
```

and bind it like this.

```
<input type=text class="form-control" name="userName" [(ngModel)]="userModel.name">
```

Comment: Changes only the form value, no change in userModel value.